# Custom Pagination using Angular JS- Need to display div elements in first page which should get repeated on 2nd page clicked Next

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

1. I have a paginated pane. I have an array of size 42. The first page shows 24 div elements and the second page shows the remaining 18 elements.
2. My question is how do I display elements 1 to 24 in page 1 and elements 19 to 42 in the second page- Meaning I need an overlapping of elements across these 2 pages.

The html code implemented is as follows:

```
    <div class = "addPage" ng-repeat="item in selectedItems.itemsArr| startFrom:currentPage*pageSize | limitTo:pageSize"> Item{{$index+1}}
    </div>
```

For the above:
pageSize=24,
currentPage=0 (Changed to 1 when Next is clicked)

The JS code to do the same is as follows(Followed this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2ZzZB/56/):

```
       .filter('startFrom', function() {
            return function(input, start) {
                if (!input || !input.length) { return; }
                else{            
                        start = +start; //parse to int
                        return input.slice(start);
                    }
             }
        });
```

[image: First 24 Items]
[image: Next 18 items]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a function in the `startFrom:` filter, you are able to control the display of the last page in the data set. This keeps your result display size consistent and gives you the overlap of data you are requiring.

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zr9nd0rx/1/

```
<li ng-repeat="item in data | startFrom: startFromCalculator()| limitTo:pageSize">


$scope.startFromCalculator = function() {
   if ($scope.currentPage + 1 == Math.ceil($scope.data.length/$scope.pageSize)) {
       return $scope.data.length - $scope.pageSize;
   } else {        
       return $scope.currentPage*$scope.pageSize;
   }
}
```